# How to render dynamic data on clicking dynamic link within the same component without refreshing the page in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a `Single Page` that renders two component `BlogDetailComponent` and `SidebarComponent` and I am passing data using props to the component. `BlogDetailComponent` renders the blog detail and `SidebarComponent` renders the `Related Blog`

In `Single Page` route I am passing the `slug` which is dynamic to get the blog details.

Below is my `vue-router` code

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Single from "../views/Single.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/blog-details/:slug",
        name: "blog_details",
        component: Single
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
});
```

Problem that I am facing -
Whenever I click on the related blog link, the slug in the route changes but does not renders the page with updated blog data for the new slug.

I have implemented using `beforeRouteUpdate`,  but the issue is that I have to call the getBlogDetail() and getRelatedBlogs() in `created()` as well as `beforeRouteUpdate` hooks in same page i.e. `Single Page` which I feel that is not the proper way to code, so any suggestion on how can I acheive this without having to call api two times in Single Page.
Below is my code for the single page

`Single Page Code`

```
import axios from 'axios'
import BlogDetailComponent from '@/components/BlogDetailComponent.vue'
import SidebarComponent from '@/components/SidebarComponent.vue'
export default {
    name: 'Single',
    components: { BlogDetailComponent, SidebarComponent },
    data() {
        return {
            blog: null,
            relatedBlogs: [],
        }
    },
    beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
        const slug = to.params.slug
        this.getBlogDetail(slug)
        this.getRelatedBlogs(slug)
        next()
    },
    created() {
        const slug = this.$route.params.slug
        this.getBlogDetail(slug)
        this.getRelatedBlogs(slug)
    },
    methods: {
        getBlogDetail(slug) {
        axios
            .get(`${process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL}/blog-detail/${slug}`)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data) {
                    this.blog = response.data
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        },
        getRelatedBlogs() {
            axios
                .get(
                    `${process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL}/blog/related/${this.$route.params.slug}`
                )
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.data) {
                        this.relatedBlogs = response.data
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added beforeRouteUpdate hooks and I am able to get data but my question is whether my implementation as mentioned in `Single Page` is correct or not. Is there any other way.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. You could trigger the event with a `watcher`:

```js
const RelatedItems = {
  template: `
    <div>
      Related items:<br />
      {{ $attrs }}
    </div>
  `,
}

const BlogItems = {
  template: `
    <div>
      Blog items:<br />
      {{ $attrs }}
    </div>
  `,
}

const ViewItems = {
  components: {
    RelatedItems,
    BlogItems,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      related: {},
      blog: {},
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route.params.slug': {
      handler(val) {
        if (val) {
          this.fetchRelated(val)
          this.fetchBlog(val)
        }
      },
      immediate: true,
      deep: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchRelated(slug) {
      const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${slug}`)
      const json = await response.json()
      this.related = json
    },
    async fetchBlog(slug) {
      const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${slug}`)
      const json = await response.json()
      this.blog = json
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col related">
        <h4>RELATED:</h4>
        <related-items
          v-bind="{
            ...this.related,
          }"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="col blog">
        <h4>BLOG:</h4>
        <blog-items
          v-bind="{
            ...this.blog,
          }"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  `
}

const routes = [{
    path: "/",
    redirect: "/1",
  },
  {
    path: "/:slug",
    component: ViewItems,
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  template: `
    <div>
      <router-link
        :to="'/1'"
      >
        ROUTE 1
      </router-link>
      <router-link
        :to="'/2'"
      >
        ROUTE 2
      </router-link><br />
      Current route: {{ $route.params }}
      <hr />
      <router-view />
    </div>
  `
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 -16px;
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  padding: 0 16px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col.related {
  width: 120px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.col.blog {
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

#### 2. Using named routes

```js
const RelatedItems = {
  // The "slug" prop is the same as the param is called
  // in the router! If you want to rename it, look at the 
  // other component for an example.
  props: ["slug"],
  data() {
    return {
      related: {},
    }
  },
  watch: {
    // watching the prop - not the $route!
    slug: {
      handler(val) {
        this.fetchRelated(val)
      },
      immediate: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchRelated(slug) {
      const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${slug}`)
      const json = await response.json()
      this.related = json
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      Related items:<br />
      {{ related }}
    </div>
  `,
}

const BlogItems = {
  // this component awaits a prop called "endpoint" - the
  // router provides that with a small twist of re-naming
  props: ["endpoint"],
  data() {
    return {
      blog: {},
    }
  },
  watch: {
    // watching the prop - not the $route!
    endpoint: {
      handler(val) {
        this.fetchBlog(val)
      },
      immediate: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchBlog(slug) {
      const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${slug}`)
      const json = await response.json()
      this.blog = json
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      Blog items:<br />
      {{ blog }}
    </div>
  `,
}

const routes = [{
    path: "/",
    redirect: "/1",
  },
  {
    path: "/:slug",
    components: {
      blogItems: BlogItems,
      relatedItems: RelatedItems,
    },
    props: {
      // renaming the param - just to have an example,
      // where the param passed as prop is modified a bit
      blogItems: (route) => ({
        endpoint: route.params.slug
      }),
      relatedItems: true,
    },
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  template: `
    <div>
      <router-link
        :to="'/1'"
      >
        ROUTE 1
      </router-link>
      <router-link
        :to="'/2'"
      >
        ROUTE 2
      </router-link><br />
      Current route: {{ $route.params }}
      <hr />
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col related">
          <h4>RELATED:</h4>
          <router-view
            name="relatedItems"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col blog">
          <h4>BLOG:</h4>
          <router-view
            name="blogItems"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 -16px;
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  padding: 0 16px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col.related {
  width: 120px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.col.blog {
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

This one is maybe a bit better if you have further plans with these components:

- visuals & data is decoupled more,
- the related & blog components are more encapsulated (thus easier to change),
- by using `props -> true` in the router, the components are easier to control from the outside, easier to reuse

---

#### 3. CONCLUSION

There are different ways to provide the same user experience - choose one, that suits your future plans:

- if this is a part of your app that won't change much and/or is not that central, then I think the first is easier to see through & maintain (remember what is happening)
- if these parts of your app might change more frequently (but the layout doesn't) and/or you'd like to build on these parts as more complex components, then I suggest the second.

I'm sure, that there are other solutions to your problem, but the baseline could be this: the router is pretty versatile. Using it with SFCs it can do virtually anything. :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I achieved my solution in a simpler way, I added <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" /> and it worked as per my requirement.